# AWS - Clave pem (FALLO SSH) Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, aws, amazon

Entro casi a diario a mi instancia de aws mediante ssh con mi clave pem, hoy cuando  intente entrar me salta el siguiente mensaje:

> Permission denied (publickey).

No he cambiando la clave pem ni nada por el estilo, simplemtente dejo de funcionar de repente.

Antes accedia mediante ssh y ftp para organizar todo, ahora no puedo acceder de ninguna manera. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola por favor incluye el error completo para ver qué puede ser

Comment: **Hola, Este es el comando que uso para entrar:**                                                 
ssh -i amazonssh.pem usuario@......amazonaws.com                                                                          
**Y esto el error que devulve:**                     
usuario@......amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Estas seguro que `usuario` es el nombre de usuario que tenes que usar? Que instancia estas utilizando? Ubuntu? Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Muchas veces los errores de:

> Permission denied (publickey).

Vienen dados por los permisos por defecto que trae la llave .pem (**0644**), trata cambiar los permisos de la llave corriendo con el siguiente comando:

```
CHMOD 0400 llave.pem
```